# When filtering a single table on only the primary key, why is the optimizer is doing a full table scan?

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I have a monster sized non-partitioned table. I recently updated the statistics as on it as well.

The primary key is on a char field called "ID".

```
SELECT * FROM "MYDATA" WHERE "ID" = '0000492319'
```

The plan is saying `TABLE ACCESS (FULL)` and has a filter predicate for the the ID.  This results in a query that takes 8 seconds to run.

If I give the optimizer a hint to use the primary key, the query takes 1.6 seconds to run.

Its bizarre to me that I should need to provide this hint. The indexed plan estimates a lower cost, and the optimizer should be aware of this.

Here is the filter predicate:

```
NLSSORT(INTERNAL_FUNCTION(ID),'nls_sort="JAPANESE_M"')=HEXTORAW('017...')
```

The database `NLS_SORT` is set to `JAPANESE_M` and the `NLS_CHARAACTERSET` is `JA16SJIS`.
So nothing seems to be mismatched that would cause a special sort function to be called.  Its a bit odd though.

One more piece of information, if I select only the "ID" column in my query then the planer chooses `INDEX (FAST FULL SCAN)` automatically.
The problem only arises when I use `select *`.

Oracle Database Verion: 10.2.0.5.0.

Comment: You should provide ddl and query plan. I assume that I see in ddl in primary key smt like this 'NLS_SORT="JAPANESE_M"'

Comment: I believe this is because of some NLS parameter mismatch between client session and database. Take a look at below threads
 

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001165/oracle-11g-case-insensitive-by-default
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533547/why-is-the-nlssort-index-not-used-for-this-query



I think in your case, the input is not treated with same NLS settings as the data, resulting in conversion and search.

Comment: In some cases, analyzing the table helps.

Comment: What is the data type of column `id`? Please run `describe "MYDATA"`; very often people *think* they know the data type, then after six days and eight answers they say "sorry, actually I was wrong, it's something different."

Comment: I am not allowed to describe the actual table, but I have verified that "ID" is CHAR(10).  Further, selecting "ID", "NAME" results in full table access whereas only selecting "ID" results in fast index searching.  I am starting to suspect that optimizer is not costing this correctly.